# Sharepoint Filter Web Part Connection To Library Web Part

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, connection, webpart-connection

I have two web parts. The provider web part is a custom web part and the consumer a library web part. In the provider web part I filter multiple values. These multiple values shall I transfer to the consumer web part to limit the results documents of the library.

My idea was to use 'Edit Web Part -> Connections -> Send Table To'. But this option 'Send Table To' is disabled.

The connection of one value is not the problem with the option 'Send Row of Data To'.

Any ideas? Thanks.